# Ошибка AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'split' discord.py[решён]

Tags: python, discord.py

Хочу добавить калькулятор в своего discord бота,но при попытке запустить команду выдаёт ошибку

> AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'split'

Вот код:

```
import simpleeval
from simpleeval import simple_eval

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def калькулятор(ctx):
        _, math_str = message.split(' ', 1)
        result = simple_eval(math_str)
        print(result)
```

Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы уверены, что ошибка возникает именно в указанной вами функции `калькулятор()`?

> AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'split'

В тексте ошибки сказано, что вы пытаетесь разбить методом `split()` не строку, а объект вашего бота - `discord.ext.commands.Bot()`, но в прикрепленной вами функции такого действия нет.

---

Зато есть другая ошибка. В этой строке:

```
 _, math_str = message.split(' ', 1)
```

Вы пытаетесь разбить неизвестный объект `message`, хотя в функцию он не был передан напрямую. Именно текст сообщения вы можете разбить получив его из контекста.

Вот так:

```
 _, math_str = ctx.message.content.split(' ', 1)
```

---

С объектом `Bot` у вас, наверное, та же ситуация. Посмотрите внимательно, что вы делаете.